# Working with unevenly spaced time series data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am working with a data set that has a timestamp, event duration, and mean value. I would like to resample the data into 15s and 60s intervals. The problem is the timestamps are unevenly spaced.

This is what I've got so far:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(length=pd.to_timedelta(30, unit='s'), value=10),
                   dict(length=pd.to_timedelta(90, unit='s'), value=30),
                   dict(length=pd.to_timedelta(180, unit='s'), value=60),
                   dict(length=pd.to_timedelta(30, unit='s'), value=10)],
                  index=[datetime(2000, 1, 1),
                         datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 30),
                         datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0),
                         datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 6, 0)])
print(df.resample('30s').mean())
```

Sample output:

```
timestamp           value
2000-01-01 00:00:00 10.0
2000-01-01 00:00:30 30.0
2000-01-01 00:01:00 NaN
...
```

**Corrected**
My desiared output would be:

```
print(df.resample('15s').mean())

timestamp           value
2000-01-01 00:00:00 5.0
2000-01-01 00:00:15 5.0
2000-01-01 00:00:30 5.0
2000-01-01 00:00:45 5.0
2000-01-01 00:01:00 5.0
...


print(df.resample('60s').mean())

timestamp           value
2000-01-01 00:00:00 20.0
2000-01-01 00:01:00 20.0
2000-01-01 00:02:00 20.0
...
```

An idea I had would be to manually upsample the data creating a record in the series for each second but this seems extremely inefficient. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: your example output doesn't make any sense. i'm confused why you say you'd like to resample to 15-sec and 60-sec intervals, but then resample and show output for a 30-sec interval.

Comment: @PaulH thanks for catching an error in my question. I have updated the output section

Answer (score 1):

If you want value/time unit, you should divide one by the other first.

```
interval = 30
df['mean_value'] = (df['value']/df['length'].apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds()/interval))
result = df['mean_value'].resample(str(interval)+'s').pad()
```

Comment: I think this will work, just to make sure I am understanding.

1. convert the value to what the value would be at that interval
2. resample to add missing intervals (60 -> 30, 30)
3. pad will use the now correct value and copy it to the new empty intervals

Answer (score 0):

I am using an optimised version of the answer suggested:

```
interval = 15
df['mean_value'] = df['value'] / (df['length'].dt.seconds / interval)
result = df['mean_value'].resample(f'{interval}s').pad()

display(result)
```